# Scrolling the application to clicked route Ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, scroll

How to make my application scroll smoothly to the beginning of the clicked route?
I have a vertical menu in my application, and when i click on an item in it i want my app to scroll down to its title. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not do that using # tags in your href?

If you are looking for 'page scrolling effects' then you could use something like http://pagescroller.com/ which is based out of jQuery.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried with # tags, it goes to that div but there is no smooth scroll to it.

Comment: For smooth scroll you would have to use animation/CSS effects to achieve the same or you could use libraries like Page scroll (link provided earlier) to handle the same thing for you!